# Does the rust format! macro provide for user-specified fill characters

Tags: rust, macros, format

With Rust I can have a user-specified width in my call to `format!`,

```
format!("{:>width$}", result.clone(), width=v as usize )
```

I can even specify the fill character (like the `-` below)

```
format!("{:->width$}", result.clone(), width=v as usize )
```

Or, with a `0`,

```
format!("{:0>width$}", result.clone(), width=v as usize )
```

But is there a way to have that user-specified? I've tried the following but it doesn't work,

```
format!("{:fill$>width$}", result.clone(), fill='0' width=v as usize )
```

I get the following error,

```
error: invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'>'`
   --> src/sequence/renderer.rs:124:28
    |
124 |                 |v| Ok(format!("{:fill$>width$}", result.clone(), fill='0', width=v as usize ))
    |                                 -      ^ expected `}` in format string
    |                                 |
    |                                 because of this opening brace
    |
    = note: if you intended to print `{`, you can escape it using `{{`

error: could not compile `letter-sequence` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. By looking at the [grammar of format string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#syntax) it's not possible to pass `fill` parameter as  an argument.

```
format := '{' [ argument ] [ ':' format_spec ] '}'
argument := integer | identifier

format_spec := [[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]['.' precision]type
fill := character
align := ''
sign := '+' | '-'
width := count
precision := count | '*'
type := '' | '?' | 'x?' | 'X?' | identifier
count := parameter | integer
parameter := argument '$'
```

As you can see the `fill` format specifier is directly mapped to a [character token](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html?highlight=character#character-literals), Where as `width` can be substituted with `identifier $`(`width` -> `count` -> `parameter` -> `argument $` -> `identifier $`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use runtime-fmt (https://crates.io/crates/runtime-fmt). The idea is to do something like this

!!! not tested !!!

```
#[macro_use] extern crate runtime_fmt;
fn main()
{
    let result = 400;
    let v = 45;
    
    let f = format!("{{:{file}>{width}}}", width=v as usize, file='0');
    let s = rt_format!(f, result).unwrap();
    println!("{}", s);    

}
```

Some interesting links:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/543
- https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html